# How do I change age-brackets in a column whilst summing the associated values in another column?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

This may be an overly-wordy question for what I am trying to ask. I have a very large dataset, with columns 'date' (day-month-year), 'age brackets' (00-04, 05-09, all the way up to 85-89, 90+) and number of cases. So in essence, there are 19 rows per date (although the original data set has 00_59 and unassigned aswell, which I will remove), and it is daily data for a year.

It's a public excel datset from Uk.gov (https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v2/data?areaType=nation&areaCode=E92000001&metric=newCasesBySpecimenDateAgeDemographics&format=csv)

What I would like to do is reduce the number of age brackets to something more manageable which will be nicer to present graphically. In this case, to brackets 00-15, 16-30, 31-45 etc (the age brackets do not particularly matter at this point in time). I want to accumulate the cases into these new age groups, whilst keeping to the day the cases were recorded. I have used the summarise, select, subset, group_by and aggregate functions previously, but I not too sure whether these are appropriate in this case (given I need to create new groups).

I haven't got code for this yet, but this is what I'm looking to do...

Original:

| Date | Age | Cases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/02/21 | 00-10 | 4 |
| 01/02/21 | 11-20 | 6 |
| 01/02/21 | 21-30 | 3 |
| 01/02/21 | 31-40 | 8 |
| 31/01/21 | 00-10 | 3 |
| 31/01/21 | 11-20 | 4 |
| 31/01/21 | 21-30 | 5 |
| 31/01/21 | 31-40 | 7 |

New:

| Date | Age | Cases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/02/21 | 00-20 | 10 |
| 01/02/21 | 21-40 | 11 |
| 31/01/21 | 00-20 | 7 |
| 31/01/21 | 21-40 | 13 |

(Again, this is a large simplification of the dataset, but that is the type of process I am looking to do).

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(Age = case_when( (Age == "00-10" | Age == "11-20") ~  "00-20",
                          (Age == "21-30" | Age == "31-40") ~  "21-40",
         TRUE ~ Age)) %>% 
  group_by(Date, Age) %>% 
  summarize(Cases = sum(Cases))
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Date [2]
  Date     Age   Cases
  <chr>    <chr> <int>
1 01/02/21 00-20    10
2 01/02/21 21-40    11
3 31/01/21 00-20     7
4 31/01/21 21-40    12
```

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(Date = c("01/02/21", "01/02/21", "01/02/21", "01/02/21", 
"31/01/21", "31/01/21", "31/01/21", "31/01/21"), Age = c("00-10", 
"11-20", "21-30", "31-40", "00-10", "11-20", "21-30", "31-40"
), Cases = c(4L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0d562498>)
```

Comment: That has done exactly what I was looking for, worked a treat! Thank you, much appreciated!